# javascript: change button text

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code:

```
<button name="calOp_enregistrer_calendrier_operateur_24" id="calOp_enregistrer_calendrier_operateur_24" type="button">Modifier</button>
```

I want change **Modifier** to **Enregistrer**.

Comment: you have to explain more

Comment: you want it to happen on click?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```js
function enregistrerCalendrierOperateur(button) {
button.innerHTML = "Enregistrer";
}
```

```html
<button name="calOp_enregistrer_calendrier_operateur_24" id="calOp_enregistrer_calendrier_operateur_24" type="button" onclick="enregistrerCalendrierOperateur(this)">Modifier</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Assuming you want to get that element via JS at any time (via event handler, Etc):**

An alternative is using the property `textContent`

```js
function enregistrerCalendrierOperateur(n) {
  document.querySelector('#calOp_enregistrer_calendrier_operateur_24').textContent = 'Enregistrer';
}
```

```html
<button name="calOp_enregistrer_calendrier_operateur_24" id="calOp_enregistrer_calendrier_operateur_24" type="button" onclick="enregistrerCalendrierOperateur(24)">Modifier</button>
```

Comment: @fatma_wings what to you expect?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#calOp_enregistrer_calendrier_operateur_24').text('Enregistrer');
```